# Данные в таблице есть, а в коде нет

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

Впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой. Вроде бы, все настроено правильно, но данных все равно нет

Startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<Context>(opt =>
        opt.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Shop;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"));
    }
```

Context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

Данные в самой таблице

[image]

Но при отладке, я вижу, что данных нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впервые сталкиваюсь с подобной проблемой. Проверял и строку подключения, и данные в базе.
Когда я попытался динамически(CRUD) добавить игру, он добавил ее в базу, но не вывел. Если нужно больше данных, я скину

Comment: db.Games.ToList();?

Comment: Ну начнём с того, что в той строчке в которой вы остановились данных и не должно быть - это пока только декларация запроса, а не выполнение запроса. Вам даже написано "Результат: если хотите посмотреть результат - помните, что начнется перечисление результата". А остальной код не видно всплывающим тултипом. Поэтому приведите нормально (текстом, не картинкой) код в вопросе и посмотрим, что там написано дальше. А код, который привёл @EvgeniyZ он как раз вызывает получение результата.